# jquery get all plugins installed into object

Tags: jquery, plugins, browser

just wondering how I can get all the browser plugins object?

I know about `navigator.plugins` method, But need an object with only the plugin name.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery and a browser that supports `navigator.plugins` (doesn't seem to include IE), then the following code will return you a Javascript array of the names of plugins present:

```
jQuery.map(navigator.plugins, function(element, index) { return element.name; });
```

EDIT: For an IE solution, see [this helpful page](http://www.builtfromsource.com/2007/06/26/detecting-plugins-in-internet-explorer-and-a-few-hints-for-all-the-others/) with some handy functions you could fairly easily use if required. Note that it doesn't show all plugins, but it does show how to determine if some of the common plugins (Flash, Java, Adobe Reader, etc) are present.